# How to parent or weight paint skirt-like element properly without clipping issues?

Tags: animation, rigging, cloth-simulation, parent

I have tried parenting it to different bone, to the model itself and changed the material to a cloth element, but it always clips through the characters legs, which I do not want to happen. Any ideas or tips?

The skirt object doesn't have to have physics, I just want it to stay in front of the legs the whole time during the animation. Really running out of ideas to try. Link to the file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OGZ2PWxq2_6VaUqEawU4CqIwqtjMrpwf?usp=sharing

[image: The issue, i want the skirt-like element to stay inside the belt and not to clip through the legs]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file (delete the useless parts): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi, I can share the file, just not sure how to add it to the post

Comment: read the instructions of the page linked, or use another platform like workupload and in both cases share the link

Comment: Done, I added a google drive link to the post

Comment: Are you talking about the top pants? Could you please post an image where you'd highlight a part that doesn't work?

Comment: I added highlighted images. the two separate meshes, they are supposed to be a part of the shirt that the character is wearing. I just haven't figured out what is the best way to connect them to the model

Comment: First you need to parent this part to the armature With Automatic Weights and see what it gives, then give some corrections in Weight Paint mode. Maybe if you remove one edge loop out of two it will make the corrections easier. Also you could try a data transfer from the body to this part. If it's still bad you could create a series of vertical bones all around the shape dedicated to move this part only?

Comment: I have tried manual weight paint, but that didn't work well. I didn't think about adding extra bones, that might work. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that may be the solution, it will give you more control on this part